# Soundcloud: search url for title

Tags: soundcloud

I've this url : http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=4346c8125f4f5c40ad666bacd8e96498&title=alejandro&limit=50

How can I change it to search query (q) only in title?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tracks resource will filter on title (and possibly description) when the general `q` parameter is passed:

`http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=4346c8125f4f5c40ad666bacd8e96498&q=alejandro&limit=50`